# Pointers and malloc.... Wrong in this code snippet

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{ 
    int *ptr = NULL;
    ptr = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int*));//memory allocation dynamically
    return 0;
}// What is the error in this type of allocation
```

Comment: You are indeed doing something wrong - do you have no idea at all what it is? (Apart from casting the result of `malloc`)

Comment: [Do not cast the return of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: I've compiled with gcc, and used *ptr = 34; no error occurs - even though the code is missing strictness.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want allocate the space for 2 ints (not 2 pointers to int):

```
int *ptr = malloc(2*sizeof(int));//memory allocation dynamically
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have understood that if you read the compilation error carefully.

```
int *ptr = NULL;
ptr = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int*)); //wrong
```

The above code is wrong. It should be:

```
ptr = malloc(2*sizeof(*ptr));
```

No need to cast the return value of `malloc`. `void *` will be safely casted. Additionally, using `sizeof(*ptr)` is easier to maintain in case ptr's data type needs to be modified.

Also, free dynamically allocated memory when its no longer needed or you will have memory leak.

```
free(ptr);
```

Comment: `sizeof(*ptr)` is not any more portable than `sizeof(int)`. Those are simply correct way compared to original `sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: Suppose I change `int *ptr` to `long *ptr`, I do not need to make any changes in allocation. If instead, I had used `sizeof(int)` it would need to be modified to `sizeof(long)`.

Comment: Yes that is true, but it has nothing to do with how portable the code is. (= does the current code run in other environment without needing to modify it)

Comment: Yes, portable is the wrong word. I should have used ease of maintenance :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies at `sizeof(int*))` and it should be `sizeof(int))`

Dynamic allocation requires you to tell what size of bytes you want it to allocate, and for that reason in this example you should use `sizeof(int)`.